# Input text into Label dynamically

Tags: jquery, label, shopify

I have noticed this has been asked a few times here but I can't find the solution that works for my issue.

I am trying to dynamically add text to my label using jQuery. I can see that the text is added in the inspect element but this is not reflected in the UI.

After adding the text using any of these :

```
$("#selection").text("My Text Here");
$("#selection").html("My Text Here");
//document.getElementById("selection").textContent = "My Text Here"
```

**Produces**

```
<input type="text" id="selection" name="properties[Selection]">My Text Here</input>
```

**But the UI remains**

[image]

Comment: input has no clsing tag. set value attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.val()`

```
$("#selection").val("My Text Here")
```

```js
$("#selection").val('My New Text Here');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="selection" name="properties[Selection]"/>
```

> **Please note :** `<input>` is a self closing tag and there isn't any
>   `</input>` for it rather it should end with `<input/>`